# android error dyld unknown required load command 0x00000022 on Mac 10.5.8

Tags: android, macos, osx-leopard

I am using Mac 10.5.8. I downloaded ADT bundle & tried to compile 'Hello World' program. But it raised error `dyld: unknown required load command 0x00000022`. & complaining about R file import. But error doesn't solve when imported.

How do I recover this error.

Comment: try deleting R.java file, clean Project and make sure you set the correct version numbers in Manifest file, properties file.

Comment: This might be a new binary vs. old OSX version compatibility issue (though 10.5.8 is of the moment still listed as supported) - see for example (with a different program, but similar sounding issue) http://asqueella.blogspot.com/2010/12/dyld-unknown-required-load-command.html

Comment: OK, I upgraded osx from panther to lion & error gone.

Comment: @enterprize, write that as answer. And they should not list Panther as supported.

Comment: @Prof.Falken: sorry not Panther, 10.5.8 I was using earlier that is Leapard. I read from some other source that there are some conflicts for android swt with Leopard, upgrade will solve issue, I do that now using Lion have no issue.

Answer (score 1):

I read from some other source that there are some conflicts for android swt with Leopard, upgrade will solve issue, I do that now using Lion 10.7  have no issue.